# Finding the most in a has_many relationship with an extra condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have a Users model that has many Polls. The Polls can be the same amongst users. The Poll model has many votes. The User Model also has many votes. The Vote model has User ID, Poll ID, and option chosen. I want to, for a given user, find the poll with the most votes.

I was looking counter_cache, but I'm not sure how to apply it to this problem. Is there a better way to solve this than iterating through each poll a user has and seeing the largest count where used_id = user_Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do this with the `counter_cache`. On the `polls` table you'd have a column `votes_count`. Your migration could look like this:

```
add_column :polls, :votes_count, :integer, default: 0
```

and the approach for finding the record would be:

```
class User
  has_many :polls
  has_many :votes
end

class Poll
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :poll, counter_cache :true
  ##attr :option_chosen
end
```

If you had some records before adding the table you need to reset the counters.

Now, to fetch the poll with the most votes, you could easily do:

`User.first.polls.order(votes_count: :desc).first`

Hope that helps.